A Python program using PyQt5 QTableWidget shows table header color correctly on Ubuntu but not on the RaspberryPi
To the reviewer who keeps closing this question, please note that this question is different to any sugegsted as being the same, in so far as I can set the table header color in Ubuntu, but not in the RaspberryPi.
If there is a solution, please let me know, but the ones suggested are unrelated.
I had a problem with a Python program running on a RaspberryPi (Pi4, running Raspbian bookworm), so I swapped to Ubuntu (22.04) and got the code to work.
When I tested the same code on the 'Pi, it didn't work.
The code is as follows:-

import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor, QFont
            
from pprint import pprint       

#Main Window 
class App(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.title = 'PyQt5 - QTableWidget'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title) 
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height) 

        self.createTable() 

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        #Show window 
        self.show() 

    #Create table 
    def createTable(self): 
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget() 

        #Row count 
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4) 

        #Column count 
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2) 

        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Name")) 
        
        pprint(dir(self.tableWidget))
        
        hhItem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem (0)

        font = QFont("arial", 20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Bertie', 'Wooster'])

        hhItem2 = QTableWidgetItem("Wooster")
        
        hhItem2.setBackground(QColor( 20, 20, 200) )

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, hhItem2)
        
        self.tableWidget.item(0,0).setBackground(QColor( 200, 200, 200) )
        
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("City")) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Aloysius")) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Indore")) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2,0, QTableWidgetItem("Alan")) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2,1, QTableWidgetItem("Bhopal")) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3,0, QTableWidgetItem("Arnavi")) 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3,1, QTableWidgetItem("Mandsaur")) 

        #Table will fit the screen horizontally 
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) 
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode( 
            QHeaderView.Stretch) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    ex = App() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 



The code was taken from a solution (Color individual horizontal headers of QTableWidget in PyQt), and modified to get it to work on my computer.
The aspiration is to be able to set the column header color (and font).

In the above image, "Bhopal" is selected, hence the column and row "titles" and in bold.
In the version on the right (on Ubuntu), the color of the header is as sought, and on the 'Pi, the same code generates a white header color.
However, the background color of the cell "Name" was set as intended!
Any help would be most appreciated.
The header should be colored - but cannot on the 'Pi, but the same code works in Ubuntu 22.04.
Please let me know if any more details are required.
Apologies if I am being silly.
(This was closed due to there being an answer - which I agree worked on Ubuntu, but did not work on the 'Pi - so any guidance to help to have the code work on the 'Pi would be appreciated.)

Some styles ignore the header background. Try with app.setStyle('fusion'), or self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion')) (and probably the same for the vertical header) if you don't want to change the whole style of the program. Alternatives exist, including using a QProxyStyle (as long as you don't use style sheets). Note names like width, height and layout are actually used for public functions of all QWidgets, and you should generally avoid to overwrite them.

is this answer your question?

As a side note, please consider that the phrase "doesn't work" is extremely ambiguous and inaccurate and should always be avoided, especially in the question title, unless properly clarified. In fact, your program does work, the problem is that one of its components doesn't work as expected. Please keep this in mind when posting new questions, as the title should always properly summarize the problem, while right now it's impossible to understand it. Titles are important for search results, so that people can easily find/discard posts without having to read all of them completely.

Many thanks for the guidance.
Sadly, the change of styles had no effect.
The link seems to propose a change to the style on a button, and changing the style didn't work.
I appreciate the comment about the subject, and I amended the subject, which hopefully is more relevant.
I still maintain that the question shouldn't be closed, as this is different to the question someone suggested it is similar to, so hopefully, it will be reopened.
Many thanks,
